# Cannot tunnel over ssh without command/getting shell

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, openssh

I would like using ssh tunneling options. For that purpose I use command:

```
ssh -L 1234:localhost:5678 host
```

however this logs me into the shell on remote host. Next I tried `-f` as:

```
 ssh -f -L 8999:localhost:6006 host
```

but I get error `Cannot fork into background without a command to execute.`

How can I get only ssh tunneling capabilities and running it in background without unnecessary clutter. My ssh version is `OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016`

Comment: `ssh -L 1234:localhost:5678 host 'sleep 30; logout'` will give you 30 seconds to start whatever you need to start that needs the tunnel, and log out of the shell.  The tunnel won't collapse until nothing is using it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the -N option

```
 -N      Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just for-
         warding ports (protocol version 2 only).
```

Example

```
ssh -fN -L 8999:localhost:6006 host
```